# Chef Best Practice Loop same recipe

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks, cookbook, recipe

Can anyone suggest in chef a best way to handle looping and running a certain recipe. For example I have this in my recipe

```
apps_databag = search("aws_opsworks_app")

apps_databag.each do |app_settings|

case app_settings['app_source']['type']
  when 's3'
   include_recipe 'recipe'
  when 'git'
   include_recipe 'recipe2'
  else
   Chef::Log.warn("*** WARNING!! Cannot find app deployment type. Please check App .. Aborting ***")
end
```

Background.. in 1 stack we have many APP that are deployed in different Server layers. We did because it cannot share RDS in two different stack. It's definitely working , now when we loop the APP we have do a trick that it will run this recipe according to it's type unfortunately include_recipe is not a good choice and for the sake of the recipe we don't want to make this recipe bloody to maintain by injecting more lines

Any suggestion for this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiples apps of each type to deploy on the same machine, move your recipe into a [custom resource/LWRP](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html).

A recipe can be included just once, so your loops won't do for multiples apps of same type.

Then you'll replace our `include_recipe` calls by resource definitions in your case statement.

Without more details on what is in your recipe, I can't give more advice on it.

Comment: Thanks! Will check this out

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are asking for. `include_recipe` is a helper to run one recipe from another. It isn't a resource per se, but you can use code basically like what you have there (give or take that it should probably be `app_settings["type"]`).